# How to automate two android app simultaneously using Appium?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, selendroid

I have to launch two app in two different devices and after completing action from one app, I have to check it from another app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up and Run two appium servers instance along with writing two different capabilities sets in your appium script as mentioned below:

1) You need 2 appium running with each different ports

```
baseUrl_1 = "http://0.0.0.0:**4726**/wd/hub"

baseUrl_2 = "http:/0.0.0.0:**4725**/wd/hub"
```

2) You need to have 2 different instances of android emulator.So make sure you just run different emulators (what i mean it can be the same version everything but the 2nd one change the name). Apparently appium was getting confuse if i run it with the same.

3) You need to set the capabilities for each emulator:

```
caps1 = {
platformName:"ANDROID",
platformVersion: "4.4",
deviceName: "emulator-5554",
app: "app1Path.apk",
       browserName: "",
```

}

```
caps2 = {
 platformName:"ANDROID",
 platformVersion: "4.4",
 deviceName: "emulator-5556",
 app: "app2Path.apk",
 browserName: ""
```

}

Comment: Thanks Raman. Its working for me using two different instances of android driver.

Comment: What if we have same activity but different flavours of app? I'm trying by package name but it's not working for me.